# JQuery serialize with complicated selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, serialization

I have form to serialize which is containing table:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr class="hide">
            <td><input /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input /></td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </table>
</form>
```

And I want use JQuery serialize, but without form elements which are in `<tr>` element with `hide` class.
I tried this:

```
$('#myForm').not('.hide').serialize()
```

But selector in `not` is looking `hide` only in form element. Is there way how to check parent closest `<tr>` element for the class in `not` selector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove elements from the form before serializing, it's probably easier to first clone the form and then remove the unwanted elements, and serialize :

```
var cloned_form = $('#myForm').clone(false);
    cloned_form.remove('.hide');

var serialized = cloned_form.serialize();
```

another way to do this would be to target all elements inside the form, and filter out anything inside a `.hide` element, like so:

```
$('*','#myForm').filter(function() {
    return !$(this).closest('.hide').length;
}).serialize();
```

Comment: I can't remove elements because after serialiazing are data posted and validating. If there are invalids values, user would need work with removed form elements.

Comment: You're not really removing anything from the form, that's the point of cloning, you're removing the elements from a copy of the form, it would be exactly the same as not selecting them in the selector.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this:

```
$("#myForm :input:not(.hide input)").serialize();
```

Comment: All elements aren't `input`, there are also `select`, `checkbox` and `textarea`.

Comment: Changed to use jQuery's `:input` pseudo-selector, which I think should match all the possible input types.